# Autohotkey Win XP automating small task

Tags: automation, windows-xp, autohotkey

I have a small task I would like to automate with Autohotkey and it looks like it is more or less directly transferable to autohotkey syntax:

```
1. Ctrl+v
2. Alt+tab
3. Click certain link in a window (no combo-key for this but it's always in the same place)
4. Enter (carriage return)
5. Alt+s
6. Ctrl+v
7. Enter
```

Now it would be nice to map this combo to something else e.g. Windows Key+Space.

What I have got so far is:

```
0. SetWinDelay 100  (using a connection to an remote computer)
0. SetKeyDelay 0
1. Send, ^c
1. ClipWait, 0.1 
2. Send, {Alt down}{tab}
2. Send, {Alt up}
3. ?????
4. Send, {enter}
5. Send, !s
6. Send, ^v
7. Send, {enter}
```

Is this approximately right? Anyone up for helping me fix it or filling in the holes, so to speak :)

Another alternative to step 3, 4 and 6 would be to simply loop though the contents of the clipboard (a number string) and sending each letter of the string to keypresses? Maybe this would be the easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "click" on a certain position, to open a menu, you can first right click on your AutoHotKey icon and open the "window spy". This window spy will show you the mouse position. Yo can use the mouse positions to perform your actions in the active application.

Example:

```
SoundBeep 1000, 300 ; Wake up user

SplashTextOn, 200, 100, Script Preparations, Please Click on the person icon link. ; Show new Instructions text

WinMove, Script Preparations,, (A_ScreenWidth/2)+150, (A_ScreenHeight/2)+200 ; Move the window with the name "Script Preparations" Down and Right on the main screen

KeyWait, LButton, D ; Wait for LeftMouseButton click Down

MouseGetPos, xposE ,yposE ; Store the position where the mouse was clicked (Employee)

MouseClick, left, %xposE% ,%yposE%, 2 ; Perform a double mouse click on the captured mouse location

SplashTextOff ; Remove Text box
```

In this case, I first ask the user to manually click on the right location. This is only required when the position to click changes WITHIN the active window (variable tiles within the active window). Once you have the position stored, you can re-use it all throughout your script.

b.t.w. instead of using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I suggest using this:

```
settitlematchmode, 1 ; Set search in title to start with....

settitlematchmode, Fast ; Slow is not required here. Slow is only required when hidden text needs to be found.

SwitchWindow("Microsoft Excel - 1 QRM Upload and Change Template") ; Activate the 
window with the title: Microsoft Excel - 1 QRM Upload and Change Template

You could even use someting like this:

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Ensure that the Title Match mode is set to 2: Find anywhere in the title

  SetTitleMatchMode, Fast ; Ensure that the Title Match mode is set to FAST

  winactivate, %WindowName% ; Activate the window with the title stored in the variable WindowName

  WinWaitActive, %WindowName%, , 5 ; Wait up to five seconds for the screen

  if ErrorLevel ; Execute this when the window is not activated within 5 seconds

  { ; Start-If Wait failed

    SoundBeep 1000 , 1000 ; Warn the user

    MsgBox,4097,Time Out, Script timed out while waiting for %WindowName%.`n`rYou Must manually activate %WindowName% and then continue the script by pressing OK. ; Message to user

    IfMsgBox, Cancel ; Do when the user clicked on Cancel

    { ; Start-If User clicked Cancel

      ExitApp ; Exit this program when the user clicked on Cancel

    } ; End-If User clicked Cancel

    WinWaitActive, %WindowName%, , 5 ; Try to activate the window AGAIN

    if ErrorLevel ; If window can't be found

    { ; Start-If window can't be found

      MsgBox,4096,Exit, %WindowName% still NOT Active. ; Warn user

      ExitApp ; Exit this program when the expected window is still not found

    } ; End-If window can't be found

  } ; End-If Wait failed
```

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: Thanks. The WinActivate came in handy and I used some sleeps after the many 'Send's I ended up using. I didn't use mouse click to change the paste mode as the contents of the clipboard could be 'pseudo-pasted' with 'Send, %clipboard%'